# Connect Notions Share Link With Custom Domain (cloudflare)

Tags: subdomain, cloudflare, cloudflare-workers, notion

as a beginner i am trying to connect Notions Share Link With Custom Domain by cloudflare. I follow this steps and now when i connect to the WIFI the website dosnt work. But with the LTE it works well.

How can i solved this problem?

Thanks

I have tried this steps:

https://stephenou.notion.site/stephenou/Fruition-Free-Open-Source-Toolkit-for-Building-Websites-with-Notion-771ef38657244c27b9389734a9cbff44